# Cannot create a sandboxed process, error code: -2147024846

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Trying to manually backup my web app + database using the Azure portal (in the `"My Web App" > Backup` blade) but I am getting the following error. Any ideas?

**Cannot create a sandboxed process, error code: -2147024846**

Here's the full log:

```
Backup Id
123209
Status
Failed
Created Time
tisdag 19 december 2017 19:00:09 CET
Download Backup Zip
Zip contains the backup of an app
Download 
Finished Time
tisdag 19 december 2017 19:09:29 CET
Size Of Backup
0MB
Log Details
Cannot create a sandboxed process, error code: -2147024846
```

Comment: It is very odd that get that error. Have you tried to restart the webapp or scale up  then scale down service plan back?

Comment: Yes, I tried stopping, starting the app. Haven't tried scale up or down. If it's not fixed by itself today I will give it a try. Still concerning with this kind of error though when it involves backing up your site plus database.

Comment: If all of that without help, you could connect [azure support team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request)  for more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems fixed now. I suspect subscription payment delay issue. 
Also, I’m on a pay as you go sub so I’m not eligible for support.